# using GCE redis click to deploy connect node.js to cluster of nodes

Tags: node.js, redis, google-compute-engine

How can I connect to redis cluster of instances? 
I am using google compute engine's click to deploy redis now it have created 3 instances all these have different ips but now how to connect to this cluster of nodes in my server.js also I am using [this redis module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) for node.js . 
My code is given below for connecting to one single instance but I don't know how to connect to the cluster of nodes.

```
var redis = require('redis');
module.exports.redis = redis.createClient('6379','107.138.209.19');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The first node in the list of instances/cluster, is redis master and this is the node you should mention in your `redis.createClient()` call. For example, if you have 3 instances like these:

- redis-1-1-vm
- redis-1-2-vm
- redis-1-3-vm

your redis master node would be **redis-1-1-vm**

You can use [Redis Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) for high-availability, i.e. deployment that resists without human intervention to certain kind of failures.

Comment: so u mean i should provide ip of redis-1-1-vm as redis url ?? ok now i have a query suppose my redis-1-1-vm is down now how my server is going to decide which vm should it call now, actually my point of being is that don't you think i should provide all three ips inside redis create client or not ?? also thanks a lot man for helping me out of here really :)

Comment: Redis does not handle failure scenarios, but Redis Sentinel *does*. Now, Redis Sentinel's ability to properly decide will depend on the situation you have set up for it. If you only have one master and two slaves, and your master dies, then one of the slaves will become master. If/when the old master comes back, it would be configured as a slave to the new master. (This assumes sufficient time between when the old master goes down and when it comes back up without data.)

Comment: Yes i want to use redis sentinel now how to use it, i don't know whether all my nodes are configured to use sentinel or not and if they are configured then how can i know they are ?? Also after using sentinel, how to pass all urls of my redis clusters in my server.js

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur - yes, all instances will be running Redis Sentinel. You should list all redis instances as mentioned and explained [here](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel-clients)